# Get list contained within map

Tags: groovy

I have the following code:

```
def bindingMap = [title: 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway',
                  'players[0]': [name: 'Steve Hackett'],
                  'players[1]': [name: 'Peter Gabriel'],
                  'players[2]': [name: 'Tony Banks']]
```

I want to get the "array" players from the map above.
So something like the line below would work:

```
def players = bindingMap.players
assert players == [[name: 'Steve Hackett'], [name: 'Peter Gabriel'], [name: 'Tony Banks']]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The sample code looks like something I probably wrote in the Grails User Guide.  If the Map you are dealing with is the request parameter Map in a Grails app, you have a number of options.  Is that the case?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Yes, I took this from Grails' documentation. I have a table of objects being built, and I tried to receive them as a parameter using List<MyClass> theListName in the controller's action, but didn't seem to work.

Comment: "I tried to receive them as a parameter using List<MyClass> theListName in the controller's action, but didn't seem to work." - See the "Data Binding and Action Arguments" subsection under http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding.  That describes the 17 supported types for special binding for controller action arguments and List<?> isn't one of them.  The 17 supported types for special binding are the 8 primitives, their 8 type wrapper counterparts and `java.lang.String`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular map structure you can `findAll` entries whose keys starts with `players` and then collect the `value` from these entries:

```
def bindingMap = [title: 'The Lamb Lies Down On Broadway',
                  'players[0]': [name: 'Steve Hackett'],
                  'players[1]': [name: 'Peter Gabriel'],
                  'players[2]': [name: 'Tony Banks']]

def players = bindingMap
    .findAll { key, value -> key.startsWith("players") }*.value
assert players == [
    [name: 'Steve Hackett'], [name: 'Peter Gabriel'], [name: 'Tony Banks']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question doesn't represent that this is about parameter binding in Grails but the comments following the question do.  Since that is what you are doing this can be done without having to write any of the parameter parsing code yourself.

```
// grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy
package demo

class DemoController {

    def index(MyCommand command) {

        // command.people will be populated if the request
        // includes parameters like...
        //    people[0].name=Jeff
        //    people[0].town='St. Louis'
        //    people[1].name='Matt'
        //    people[1].town='San Jose'

        // ...
    }
}

class MyCommand {
    List<People> people
}

class People {
    String name
    String town
}
```

This has a number of benefits over writing your own parameter parsing code.

Comment: Note that depending on what you are doing, you may be able to skip the command object altogether.  The question doesn't include enough detail about what you are trying to accomplish to say for sure if that is relevant here or not.  Normally this is done in the context of creating or updating domain objects and for those this could be made even more simple.